# display the horizantal scrollbar always(even on empty) in CListctrl using vc++

Tags: visual-c++

background :-

I have 2 list control in my dialog wherein I am synchronising the vertical scroll with both of them. synchronising is fine but I have issue when the one of the clistctrl has the horizontal scrollbar and the other does not have. Since the scrollbar will consume some space inside the Clistctrl which will lead to mismatch the scroll position of the other when we are at the extreme bottom of the scrollbar.

I tried changing the styles of the list control in OnInitdialog() before populating the data but it is not working.
Can anyone provide the solution to my problem?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: So I need to display the horizontal scrollbar even when the Clistctrl data is empty.

Comment: You did not mention what UI library you are using. I assume this is an ancient MFC, since you mentioned OnInitDialog. If so, just add WS_HSCROLL to the list box control.

Comment: I am using VS2010 Professional. I tried adding m_listctrl.ShowScrollBar(WS_HSCROLL,TRUE), but it did not worked.

Comment: The parameter to ShowScrollBar are different: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcs3129s.aspx. The first parameter takes values SB_VERT, SB_HORZ and SB_BOTH.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! As you said I changed the second parameter value to SB_HORZ but even then it didn't work. Is it possible to enable the scrollbar when the listctrl is empty?